# Кортеж - это костыль?

Tags: python, кортежи

Я поспорил с другом. Давайте разовьём дискуссию. Я ставлю - что да, поскольку кортедж - тот же список, но как строка. Но ведь тогда словарь - список списков (кортеж кортежей)?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142994/discussion-on-question-by-mrsvinia---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 2):

Это всё разные объекты, они все нужны:

- кортеж иммутабелен (неизменяем), поэтому он в какой-то степени экономит место и предохраняет элементы от изменения (тоже в какой-то степени)
- список же наоборот заточен под возможность лёгкого его расширения, из-за чего он не так оптимален по месту хранения (возможность быстрого расширения заставляет выделять память блоками) и не может быть ключом словаря
- словарь это хэш таблица с моментальным (в идеале) доступом к элементам по ключу (в отличие от списка и кортежа, где быстрый доступ идёт по индексу, а ключей никаких нет)
- строка также иммутабельна, как и кортеж, но сильно заточена под разные символьные операции

Comment: То бишь кортеж это NAND, а список NOR?

Comment: @MrSvinia Я сходу так в этих терминах не сориентируюсь )  Но видимо да

Comment: Прикольно, тогда получается, что SSD диски - костыли. РАЗРЫВНАЯ.

Comment: @MrSvinia Возьмите вместо термина **костыль** термин **компромисс** и хорошенько над ним подумайте. Может так понятнее будет. Да, современные `SSD` диски - это компромисс: менее надёжно, зато сильно дешевле.

Comment: Прикольно. У меня компьютер-мутант есть, ему тринадцать лет, а он до сих пор пашет. Потому что у него SSD! Костыли - просто средство ускорения инвалидов. (Никого не оскорбляю, осуждаемое - осуждаю)

Comment: @MrSvinia такое впечатление, что вы хотите поделить сложный мир по простому принципу "костыль-не костыль", найти какие-то простые ответы на сложные вопросы. Но нет такого простого принципа. Все для чего-то для какой-то цели нужно, даже то что вам по какой-то причине хочется отнести к "костылям".